# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: breeze.linalg.squaredDistance

Tags: maven, apache-spark, scala-breeze

I want to run a Spark Streaming program on a cluster. 
Despite my program runs correctly locally on my machine, run on the cluster problem. In fact, I get this error as:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: breeze.linalg.squaredDistance$.distanceFromDotAndSub(Lbreeze/generic/UFunc$UImpl2;Lbreeze/generic/UFunc$UImpl2;)Lbreeze/generic/UFunc$UImpl2;
```

Why it runs locally when it is not on the cluster ?!

I added the **breeze** dependency as follows:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scalanlp</groupId>
  <artifactId>breeze_${scala.version}</artifactId>
  <version>0.11.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: don't use 0.11.1, which has a critical bug. Use 0.11.2

Answer (score 0):

thats probably because dependency is available in your classpath locally but not on worker nodes.
Make a fat/uber jar which includes the dependency and then try.

Refer [this](http://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/missing_dependencies_in_jar_files.html)